# Always On AG and WSFC

Tags: ag

I am trying to configure an Always On AG in 2 nodes , SQL server version is 2019.

One of the prerequisites that AG require WSFC , can anyone explain why WSFC is required ? as we know each node in AG has its own drives and no shared disk in AG.

Another question , in case of enabling WSFC and AG , does it required to create a disk quorum for voting mechanism ?